# Using transient attributes in Core-Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, transient

I am not sure whether using transient attribute is the correct way for my situation. I am getting kind of feeds from server and stores in the core data. Am showing all these feeds in a TableView. There are many types of feeds, so cell layout and subviews vary with each feed. In some feeds, I need to set a temporary variable (BOOL and Integer. So NSNumber I know). The use case is, user should be able to enlarge and collapse some of the cells (A kind of "Read more.." link). So this state, I need to keep with each feed(NSManagedObject) object. This state will be there till app is running. It should not be saved to persistence storage because when user opens the app, all feed should be fresh.

I just added attribute with transient but it seems not working. I added 'NSNumber selected' attribute in entity as transient and added property and @dynamic in NSManagedObject file. I searched the forum and no solution is matching with mine. I tried with many sample stuffs but it really confusing..

Interface file is,

```
@interface FeedItemBase : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * premium;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *selected; //This is what I added

@end
```

Implementation file is,

```
@implementation FeedItemBase
@dynamic timestamp;
@dynamic type;
@dynamic premium;
@dynamic selected; //This is what I added

@end
```

So please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to query it, just add a regular BOOL to your managed object subclass.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL selected; //This is what I added
```

and in your .m file

```
@synthesized selected = _selected;
```

Transient properties in core data have so many odd edge cases; in my experience, I avoid them if I can.

Comment: Hi thanks for your kind answer. My doubt is, if we use like this, how app can keep the state of this variable till app cycle ends? I'll explain it. I am using NSFetchResultController. So it will not keep the NSManagedObject in memory. Instead it will get when we wants it. So in this case, if I set value and scroll the table view, NSFetchResultController will discard the NSManagedObject, so the variable state too. When user comes back to the same cell, NSFetchResultController will get the appropriate NSManagedObject from CoreData but the variable with default value.

Comment: Core Data Transient attributes are probably not what you want.  You might try keeping state in memory in the view controller or something.    The other alternative is to use a traditional core data attribute and just clear it when the app loads.  (this might not be feasible for large collections though).

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I got a direction. I'll try that ways.

Comment: Hadhi,Respectfully, do you have evidence that the NSFetchedResultsController releases managed objects it isn't currently displaying? In my experience, it retains these items. My ivars that are preserved. This is relatively easy to test with a breakpoint when the cell is configured.

Comment: @adonoho. No. I've not tried that but I believe it will not retain NSManagedObject. If so, there is no difference between using an array of all NSManagedObjects and NSFetchResultController. The memory foot print will be same. Anyway I'll do a try as you said. Really thanks for your input.